# Is "county subdivision" geography supported for get_acs()

Tags: tidycensus

I'm trying to upload data for "county subdivision" as part of the geography options in tidycensus' get_acs() function. I know there are several geography options, which Kyle Walker has published on his page. https://walkerke.github.io/tidycensus/articles/basic-usage.html#geography-in-tidycensus

And while it works fine for state and county level, because you would just put county = "Monmouth". But I can't seem to get the syntax to work at the city subdivision level for a city within Monmouth county. I've looked for other tidycensus scripts, but haven't found any using geographies below County level.

Any suggestions?

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

census_api_key("YOUR API KEY GOES HERE")

vars <- c(English = "C16002_002", 
      Spanish = "C16002_003")


language <- get_acs(geography = "county subdivision", 
                state = "NJ",
                county = "Monmouth",
                city = "Red Bank",
                table = "C16001")



rb_language <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
                   variables = vars,
                   state = "NJ", 
                   county = "Monmouth", 
                   city = "Red Bank"
                   geometry = TRUE, 
                   summary_var = "C16002_001") %>%
  st_transform(26918)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear if you are trying to get data for the Red Bank county subdivision or census tracts *within* Red Bank. In either case, you can't do this directly in `tidycensus`, but rather you can get all subdivisions or tracts in a county using `get_acs()` and then further filter the results.

For example, if you just want language data for Red Bank county subdivision, you could do this:

```r
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(tigris)

vars <- c(English = "C16002_002", 
          Spanish = "C16002_003")

# get all subdivisions in monmouth county
language_subdiv <- get_acs(geography = "county subdivision", 
                           state = "NJ",
                           county = "Monmouth",
                           table = "C16001")

# only red bank borough
language_subdiv %>% 
  filter(str_detect(NAME, "Red Bank"))
#> # A tibble: 38 x 5
#>    GEOID     NAME                                  variable  estimate   moe
#>    <chr>     <chr>                                 <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…    11405   171
#>  2 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…     7227   451
#>  3 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…     3789   425
#>  4 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…     1287   247
#>  5 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…     2502   435
#>  6 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…        0    19
#>  7 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…        0    19
#>  8 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…        0    19
#>  9 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…       42    40
#> 10 34025624… Red Bank borough, Monmouth County, N… C16001_0…        0    19
#> # ... with 28 more rows
```

Now, if you wanted census tracts within Red Bank, you could grab all census tracts in Monmouth, then use `tigris::places()` to get the boundaries of Red Bank, and finally filter the census tracts to only get those tracts that are contained by the Red Bank boundary.

```r
# get all tracts in monmouth county
language_tract <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
                          variables = vars,
                          state = "NJ", 
                          county = "Monmouth",
                          geometry = TRUE, 
                          summary_var = "C16002_001", 
                          output = "wide")

# get geometry of red bank borough 
red_bank_place <- places("NJ", cb = TRUE, class = "sf") %>% 
  filter(NAME == "Red Bank")

# only tracts in red bank borough
red_bank_tracts <- language_tract %>% 
  filter(st_contains(red_bank_place, ., sparse = FALSE))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = red_bank_tracts, color = "blue", fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = red_bank_place, color = "black", fill = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. This is the exact geography I was getting at. I'll need to look at how to fill the ggplot because in my original code, I was able to look at the proportion of English and Spanish-speakers. Looked pretty cool and answers my research questions very nicely :)